# generate images with labels from a database

Tags: image, automated-tests

I need to have some images into my database, and the thing is that i need that images to have certain file names, dimensions and text on it.

I know how to generate some images using the opencv lib, but this means that i need to install the lib and do just that job(which sounds as reinventing the wheel). Do you think is worth to do that or maybe you have a better idea?

ps: the images are for testing stage of a software application, so i don;t need anything fancy or artistic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd download [the Berkeley dataset](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/).  I don't know the number of images you require, but there's a bunch there, and you can also get the segmented versions as well.  You probably don't need the segmentations for your purposes, but hey.